# Parse Server push from Parse Dashboard error: Missing push configuration

Tags: android, cordova, parse-platform, push-notification, ionic2

I used the [following tutorial](https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/gcm-setup-for-android-push-notifications-656cfdd8adbd#.2kledkply) to configure my Ionic 2 Android push configuration in conjunction with the [Taivo-Parse-Plugin](https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin) Ionic/Parse Plugin. I'm trying to send a Push notification from the Parse Dashboard. The tutorial seems pretty straight forward. I did notice that the UI labeling in the tutorial calling the long apiKey "Firebase Cloud Messaging Token" has been changed to "Server Key" in my UI. Everything else in the Google UI is the same.

Although this is an android app it is built with Javascript; please present Javascript/Ionic answers if possible.

Comment: same error here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @espa_network thanks for asking. I didn't find a lot out there that was helpful. I ultimately abandoned it and I think you may have to just use the Ionic Push. The Parse Dashboard as it currently exists doesn't allow you to actually select specific channels for push. At the end of the day it wasn't immediately mission critical so we've kicked the can down the road. If you find anything I'd love to hear about it via your answer!

Comment: Keep researching! I'll let you know if I find something.

Comment: @espa_network - agreed. If/when I get an answer I will post it here.

Comment: did you find anything?